# Trying to determine if a triangle is a right triangle in C using the Epsilon rule

Tags: c, pythagorean

- I've been making this code to determine if a triangle can be a right triangle **without** using sqrt() or abs() by taking three sides and figuring out if the absolute difference between them is less than Epsilon, or 0.05. But it only works in some cases. What am I doing wrong?

```
int IsRightTriangle(float side1, float side2, float side3)
{
    if (side3*side3-(side1*side1+side2*side2) <= 0.05 || side3*side3-(side1*side1+side2*side2) >= -0.05) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (side1*side1-(side3*side3+side2*side2) <= 0.05 || side1*side1-(side3*side3+side2*side2) >= -0.05) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (side2*side2-(side3*side3+side1*side1) <= 0.05 || side2*side2-(side3*side3+side1*side1) >= -0.05) {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

I have tried multiple iterations of this code, and they all got results similar to this:

```
Running test: IsRightTriangle(edge1=15.00, edge2=27.00, edge3=29.55)  --  Passed
Running test: IsRightTriangle(edge1=21.02, edge2=19.00, edge3=9.00)  --  Failed
```

Comment: Why you even want a `sqrt` or `abs`? The mathematical test for whether a and b are the lengths of the sides of a right triangle with hypotenuse length c is whether a^2 + b^2 = c^2. No square root, no absolute value.

Comment: Your mention of 0.05 and and “Epsilon rule” suggests the teacher (or other person posing this task) expects you to use an often misunderstood floating-point comparison, to test whether the computation `a*a + b*b` is within some “epsilon” of `c*c` as a proxy for determining whether the mathematical a^2+b^2 = c^2 holds. To do that, compute `a*a + b*b` and `c*c` and test whether they differ by less than some threshold amount.

Comment: Your sample output shows the test program reporting whether tests passed or failed, but it does not show what result is expected from `IsRightTriangle` for the cases shown. That is, we do not know whether `IsRightTriangle` returned 0 and the test passed because it was expected to return 0 or it returned 0 return 1 and the test passed because it was expected to return 1, and conversely for the failing case. State what return values are expected from those cases.

Comment: As above, there exists no "epsilon rule" for right triangles, but there is the usual epsilon for imprecise floating point comparisons.

Comment: Some numerical tinkering suggests the target test the problem poser intends is whether the ideal hypotenuse length corresponding to the two sides is within .005 of the given hypotenuse length. E.g., since the numbers are given with two digits after the decimal point, they might come from some number within .005 of the given number. E.g., 21.0237 is close to the hypotenuse for 19 and 9, and rounding that to two digits gives 21.02. So one test could be whether (c-.005)^2 is less than a^2+b^2 and (c+.005)^2 is greater than a^2+b^2…

Comment: … That only allows wiggle room for the hypotenuse, though. You might want to allow wiggle room for all the numbers. The question should be fully stated with all details.

Comment: Let a0=a−.005, b0=b−.005, c0=c−.005, a1=a+.005, b1=b+.005, and c1=c+.005. If `a0*a0 + b0*b0 <= c1*c1` and `a1*a1 + b1*b1 >= c0*c0`, then it is possible a, b, and c are numbers that come from rounding the lengths of the sides and hypotenuse of a right triangle to two decimal digits after the decimal point, because there are some real numbers a', b', and c' in those intervals (or very near, due to additional rounding with converting, add, and subtracting .005) that form those lengths. That might be the test the problem poser intended.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/6Nqo3t

Comment: @Omer Rudnick,  ".   without using sqrt() or abs()" --> `abs()` is an integer function.  Did you mean `fabs()` and friends?

Comment: @Omer Rudnick "less than Epsilon, or 0.05." is a weak choice.  The compare deserves to be scale to the magnitudes of the sides.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

I'd expect `&&` instead of `||` as the compare needs to meet both conditions to be a "right" triangle.

Think of

```
if (side3*side3-(side1*side1+side2*side2) <= 0.05 || side3*side3-(side1*side1+side2*side2) >= -0.05) { 
    return 1;
}
```

as

```
double d = side3*side3-(side1*side1+side2*side2);
if (d <= 0.05 || d >= -0.05) {
    return 1;
}
```

`d <= 0.05 || d >= -0.05` is always true (unless sides had a not-a-number).
Certain it should use `d <= 0.05 && d >= -0.05`.
Other issues exist too.

---

> Trying to determine if a triangle is a right triangle

Suggested alternative algorithm:

1. Determine the the side with the largest magnitude squared - the candidate [hypotenuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotenuse) squared.  This negates the need for square root and absolute value.
2. Sum the other 2 squares.
3. *Relatively* compare the two for nearness to 1.0 (a right triangle).
   Code is dealing with *floating point* values.
   `IsRightTriangle(15.00    , 27.00    , 29.55)` should get the same result as
   `IsRightTriangle(15.00e10 , 27.00e10 , 29.55e10)` and as
   `IsRightTriangle(15.00e-10, 27.00e-10, 29.55e-10)`.

Example: Lightly tested sample code:

```
int IsRightTriangle(float side1, float side2, float side3) {
  double sq[3];
  sq[0] = 1.0 * side1 * side1; // Use double math for extra precision and range.
  sq[1] = 1.0 * side2 * side2;
  sq[2] = 1.0 * side3 * side3;

  if (sq[1] < sq[2]) {
    swap(&sq[1], &sq[2]);
  }
  if (sq[0] < sq[1]) {
    swap(&sq[0], &sq[1]);
  }
  // sq[0] is now the largest.

  double hypotenuse = sq[0];
  double sum_of_smaller2 = sq[1] + sq[2];

  if (hypotenuse == 0.0) {
    return 1; // Degenerate case, all sides 0.
  }

  // How close to 1.0 is sum_of_smaller2/hypotenuse?
  #define Epsilon 0.05
  // Use the square as the we are testing the square of magnitudes.
  #define Epsilon2 (Epsilon * Epsilon)
  double ratio = sum_of_smaller2 / hypotenuse;
  return (1.0 - Epsilon2 <= ratio) && (ratio <= 1.0 + Epsilon2);
}
```

---

Notes:

- `double` or `float`?  OP is using `float` arguments, yet `double` constants and discusses `double` functions like `sqrt()` instead of `sqrtf()`.
- `abs()` is an integer function and has no place here.  Instead discuss `fabs()`, `fabsf()`.